# Can an inanimate 'experience' an event?

Tags: word-usage

In the geological context, can a mountain range 'experience' upheaval. Or could a statue 'experience' acid rain? Is their a better verb to use when events 'happen' to an object that is not conscious?

Answer (score 1):

We can use 'experiences' with an object or thing, which does not have to be conscious, or even alive, to discuss actions performed on it, or something undergone by it.

> This is observable evidence that an object moving in circular motion
>   at constant speed experiences an acceleration that is directed towards
>   the center of the circle.

[Acceleration](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circles/Lesson-1/Acceleration)

> Experience
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Encounter or undergo (an event or occurrence)
>
> ‘the company is experiencing difficulties’

[Experience (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/experience)